# Force override camera image on android

Tags: android, image, camera, overriding

Is there any way to force the android camera to see a specific thing, like an image?

I have an app called FakeGPS, and basically, any system that tries to use Android's GPS methods will get the fake coordinates that I setup using that app.

I want to do the exact same thing, except with the camera.

Any app using the camera will get the image that I put in.

Comment: the question is not close to precise. what EXACTLY do you want to achieve?

Comment: sorry, I rephrased my question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The camera implementation is completely native, everything works with IPC calls between the system and the camera driver (that are provided by the different manufactor).

There is no way to intercept this chain without recompiling the entire OS.

You can find more info [here](http://multimediadroid.blogspot.it/2012/02/android-camera.html).

Answer (score 1):

as @dmarcato said - if you want to manipulate anything with the camera that would be relevant to every camera application - only way is to change android's native source code somehow - something that can be done only when compiling android OS image containing this changes.

so, if you are not going to provide to each one of your user a custom OS firmware (for each device you want to support - it's different image containing the specific binaries drivers..)   you can forget about that.

if that's not enough, there is also the issue that native core camera code is not necessarily android code, but vendor specific code which probably entirely different on each device.  this means that you probably need to implement your "hack" different for each device image to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite unclear what you are trying to say. I guess you want to force setting some app to be used for specific files or content type. Setting default app from your code is impossible. Only user can choose their default apps for specific operation or content type.

But still you can run specific system app, BUT only from your application, like launching any system camera, regardless of the phone manufacturer:

```
Intent systemCamera = null;
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    for(ApplicationInfo packageInfo:packages){
        Intent i =  pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName);
        if(i != null && i.getAction().equals(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)){
            if((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)!= 0){ //check if system app
                systemCamera = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    startActivityForResult(systemCamera, MY_POSITIVE_INTEGER_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work on rooted devices. You can use things like xposed http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer to modify the methods used by normal apps to grab camera images. This won't work for recording or system native apps thought.
There you need other tools. If you want to do it globally and right at the camera source, you might need to build your own android kernel. But that's not that hard either. The issue there is that you will have to build another kernel for each device and firmware version.

Answer (score -4):

At first glance, what you are wanting to do seems unethical.

Unless you are willing to modify kernel or system libraries, it is also impossible.